# How to generate grid in sass like stylus?

Tags: css, sass

I can generate grid in stylus:

```
generate-grid(mod)
 total = 0
 for n, x in 0..11
   total = round(8.3333333% * (x + 1))
   .{mod}-{x + 1}
     flex 0 0 total
   .offset-{mod}-{x + 1}
     margin-left total
```

But if I do this in sass then I'll get a bunch of mistakes. How to do it correctly?

```
@function generate-grid() {
  @for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-{$i} {
      width: 8.3333333% * $i;
    }
    .offset-{$i} {
      margin-right: 8.3333333% * $i;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interpolation is different than stylus in sass, it use `#{}`:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____